# Database connection MySQL or Berkeley DB

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, apache, berkeley-db

Ive just recently learned SQL. There seems to be a few concepts I cant understand. Please check my statements. SQL is a language you are using to access data in MySQL? MySql is a software for a database server? So this means you can buy your own computer hardware and install MySql there and you can access your files in that specific hardware? Or is MySql only installed in hardwares owned by Oracle and you can only access files there by registering in Oracle?

Here is an example please correct the statement. Im trying to build a website for my students that take in a username and password. This website will use a scripting language that will connect to a database server. So I upload my xhtml, css files, and some scripting language to a webhost. Then those scripting files will connect me to my database server? This means I should have a database server. The database server are MySql, Appache Cassandra. To connect to  those database server do I need my own harver server that has these database server installed or do I obtain membership from Oracle(?), Appache(?) to access there database server or is there other ways to store data?  I think you guys can see my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You could say SQL is a standardized language to work with relational databases like MySQL, SQL Server Oracle, PostgreSQL etc They conform more or less to the standardized SQL language

MySQL is open source you can install it on just about any major OS / hardware architecture, for free you don't have to pay anyone anything except for support if you require that

It's possible to host your database on a server and allow remote apps to connect to it.

Apache Cassandra isn't exactly a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is learn to use Google to search for answers to your basic questions. I also recommend Wikipedia.org.

Those two websites can help you learn about what SQL is, MySQL is, scripting languages are, and what servers are.

I'll throw you a bone here. MySQL, PHP, and Apache (1 "p", not 2) are all free software. You can install them on "Windows" or "Linux".

If you're running Windows, also try using Google to research "WAMP stack" or "WAMP".